# Mongo fetch object with distinct criteria values

Tags: mongodb

We recently moved from MySql to mongo.

I need to fetch last X docuemnts of distinct players with time condition
for example

example:

```
{"id":A1, "time":"2019-07-01", "player":"AA"},
{"id":A2, "time":"2019-07-02", "player":"AA"},
{"id":A3, "time":"2019-07-03", "player":"BB"},
{"id":A4, "time":"2019-07-04", "player":"CC"},
{"id":A5, "time":"2019-07-05", "player":"DD"},
{"id":A6, "time":"2019-07-06", "player":"CC"},
```

Lets say I want to fetch 2 players events that had occurred before the 5th:

```
{"id":A2, "time":"2019-07-02", "player":"AA"},
{"id":A3, "time":"2019-07-03", "player":"BB"},
```

How can I do this?

- one query?
- two queries?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well what you mean with the `time condition` you mentioned.

If you need to retrieve players events between **two dates** you can do:

```
db.getCollection("your_collection").find({
    "id": {$in: ["A2", "A3"]}, 
    "time": {$gte: "2019-07-02", $lte: "2019-07-03"}
});
```

If you need to retrieve players events **before some date**, you can:

```
db.getCollection("your_collection").find({
    "id": {$in: ["A2", "A3"]}, 
    "time": {$lt: "2019-07-03"}
});
```

The operators used here are straighforward:

[$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/): filter documents where a field value equals any value of the array.
[$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/): filter documents where a field value is less than a value.
[$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/): filter documents where a field value is less than or equal a value.
[$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/): filter documents where a field value is greater than or equal a value.

Comment: Thanks But i need distinct players

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get you the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            "time":{
                $lt:"2019-07-05"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$id",
            "id":{
                $first:"$id"
            },
            "time":{
                $first:"$time"
            },
            "player":{
                $first:"$player"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:{
            "time":-1
        }
    },      
    {
        $limit:2
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{ "id" : "A4", "time" : "2019-07-04", "player" : "CC" }
{ "id" : "A3", "time" : "2019-07-03", "player" : "BB" }
```

Aggregation stages info:

- Stage I: Filter records which have 'time' less than "2019-07-05"
- Stage II: Grouping on the basis of player 'id'. It would result in distinct players.
- Stage III: Sorting on the basis of 'time'. As we would need last X records.
- Stage IV: Limiting the records as required. 2 records in this example.
- Stage V: Eliminating unnecessary fields from the output.